# Matching DataFrames based on column value being a subset

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two pandas DataFrames:

```py
import pandas as pd
source_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Total": [315.59, 241.17, 165.87],          
                                    "Label": ["id|1234", "id|2345", "id|2333"]})
    Total    Label
0  315.59  id|1234
1  241.17  id|2345
2  165.87  id|2333
```

and

```py
match_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {"Labels": ["id|1234; id|4957", "id|7632", "id|2345; id|9342", "id|2333; id|8321; id|9001"]})
                      Labels
0           id|1234; id|4957
1                    id|7632
2           id|2345; id|9342
3  id|2333; id|8321; id|9001
```

I would like to replace the `Label` values in `source_df` using the `Labels` values in `match_df`, selecting the row where the `source_df.Label` is in `match_df.Labels`. The desired output would therefore be:

```py
    Total                      Label
0  315.59           id|1234; id|4957
1  241.17           id|2345; id|9342
2  165.87  id|2333; id|8321; id|9001
```

My approach to doing this at the moment relies on a pairwise comparison between the DataFrames using `iterrows`, which is notoriously slow and to be avoided:

```py
for ii, row in source_df.iterrows():                                            
    for _, match_row in match_df.iterrows():                                    
        if row.Label in match_row.Labels:                                       
            source_df.at[ii, "Label"] = match_row.Labels                        
            break
```

Is there a more pythonic and efficient way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+) by lists of `Labels` created by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), so possible use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = match_df.assign(Label = match_df['Labels'].str.split('; ')).explode('Label')

df = source_df.merge(df1, on='Label')
print (df)
    Total    Label                     Labels
0  315.59  id|1234           id|1234; id|4957
1  241.17  id|2345           id|2345; id|9342
2  165.87  id|2333  id|2333; id|8321; id|9001
```

Last reassing column `Label`:

```
df['Label'] = df.pop('Labels')
print (df)
    Total                      Label
0  315.59           id|1234; id|4957
1  241.17           id|2345; id|9342
2  165.87  id|2333; id|8321; id|9001
```

Another solution with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {y: x for x in match_df['Labels'] for y in x.split('; ')}

source_df['Label'] = source_df['Label'].map(d)
print (source_df)
    Total                      Label
0  315.59           id|1234; id|4957
1  241.17           id|2345; id|9342
2  165.87  id|2333; id|8321; id|9001
```